# Is it possible to retrieve false positive and false negative from confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have generated a confusion matrix using R as follows.

Is it possible to retrieve the false negative value of 61 from this matrix and assign to a variable in R? $byClass does't seem to work for this case. 
Thanks.

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

              Reference
    Prediction   no  yes
           no  9889   61
           yes    6   44

               Accuracy : 0.9933          
                 95% CI : (0.9915, 0.9948)
    No Information Rate : 0.9895          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 4.444e-05       

                  Kappa : 0.5648          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 4.191e-11       

            Sensitivity : 0.9994          
            Specificity : 0.4190          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.9939          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8800          
             Prevalence : 0.9895          
         Detection Rate : 0.9889          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.9950          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7092          

       'Positive' Class : no
```

Comment: Please give a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248

Comment: Perhaps `as.matrix()` would allow you to get at the individual values in the confusion matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't provided a reproducible example or loaded any packages in your code, but it looks like you're using `confusionMatrix` from the `caret` package. Here's a generic example:

```
library(caret)

# Fake data
dat = data.frame(measured=rep(0:1, c(40,60)), modeled=rep(c(0:1,0:1), c(30,10,20,40)))

# Generate confusion matrix
cm = confusionMatrix(dat$modeled, dat$measured, positive="1")

cm
```

> ```
> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
>
>           Reference
> Prediction  0  1
>          0 30 20
>          1 10 40
>
>                Accuracy : 0.7             
>                  95% CI : (0.6002, 0.7876)
>     No Information Rate : 0.6             
>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.02478         
>
>                   Kappa : 0.4             
>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.10035         
>
>             Sensitivity : 0.6667          
>             Specificity : 0.7500          
>          Pos Pred Value : 0.8000          
>          Neg Pred Value : 0.6000          
>              Prevalence : 0.6000          
>          Detection Rate : 0.4000          
>    Detection Prevalence : 0.5000          
>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.7083          
>
>        'Positive' Class : 1
> ```

`cm` is actually a list, so let's see what it contains:

```
str(cm)

List of 6
 $ positive: chr "1"
 $ table   : 'table' int [1:2, 1:2] 30 10 20 40
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ Prediction: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. ..$ Reference : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
 $ overall : Named num [1:7] 0.7 0.4 0.6 0.788 0.6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Accuracy" "Kappa" "AccuracyLower" "AccuracyUpper" ...
 $ byClass : Named num [1:11] 0.667 0.75 0.8 0.6 0.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11] "Sensitivity" "Specificity" "Pos Pred Value" "Neg Pred Value" ...
 $ mode    : chr "sens_spec"
 $ dots    : list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "confusionMatrix"
```

It looks like `cm$table` has the actual confusion matrix:

```
cm$table
```

> ```
>           Reference
> Prediction  0  1
>          0 30 20
>          1 10 40
> ```

So the count of false positives is:

```
cm$table[2,1]
```

> ```
> [1] 10
> ```

Comment: Thanks. That is just what I am looking for.